# Marshalling of C Struct as return value of C# delegate

Tags: c#, .net, c, interop, marshalling

I'm attempting to return a small (8 byte) struct by value from a delegate bound to a native function, but am running into the following error when targeting the .NET Framework 2.0 (the code seems to work correctly when targeting 4.0+):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in testclient.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I suspect I've messed up the managed type annotations such that the return value isn't being marshalled correctly, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Below is the code for a small native test DLL and managed client which reproduces the problem.

#### C/C++ Win32 (x86) test DLL

```
//Natural alignment, blittable, sizeof(StatusBlock) == 8
struct StatusBlock{
    std::uint32_t statusA;
    std::uint32_t statusB;
};

/*
 * When compiled this function stores the 64bit return value in the
 * eax:edx register pair as expected.
 */
static StatusBlock __cdecl SomeFunction(std::uint32_t const someVal){
    return StatusBlock{ someVal, 0x1234ABCD };
}

//Exported
extern "C" PVOID __stdcall GetFunctionPointer(){
    return &SomeFunction;
}
```

#### C# test client

```
class Program
{

    //Blittable, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(StatusBlock)) == 8
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct StatusBlock
    {
        public UInt32 statusA;
        public UInt32 statusB;
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate StatusBlock SomeFunction(UInt32 someVal);

    [DllImport("testlib.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetFunctionPointer();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fnPtr = GetFunctionPointer();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(fnPtr != IntPtr.Zero);

        var someFn = (SomeFunction)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fnPtr, typeof(SomeFunction));
       
        /* 
         * Crashes here with a System.AccessViolationException when targeting .NET Framework 2.0.
         * Works as expected when targeting .NET Framework 4.0 +
         */
        var statusBlock = someFn(22);
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that if the return type of the delegate is `Uint64` the application works as expected in both the .NET 2.0 and 4.0 case. However, I shouldn't have to do this; `StatusBlock` should marshal correctly.

Have I just been lucky when targeting .NET 4.0? Any insight into what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: The abi for struct return values is ill defined. You'd be better off with an out param.

Comment: I repro.  Looks like the CLR generates a bad stub for the delegate, hard to debug however.   You'll need help from Microsoft Support to get ahead, difficult with such an old .NET version.

Comment: Damn, .NET's stupid. I think I figured the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It is by all means fault in .NET.

### tl;dr

.NET Framework 2 generates an incorrect (possibly insecure) stub.

### How did I find this out?

I conducted some tests:

1. Instead of a 8-byte long struct, I used 4-byte long struct. It works!
2. Instead of using x86, I used x64. It works!

Figuring out that it works in all other cases, I decided to native-debug it with windbg to see where it crashes (because Visual Studio won't allow me to "step in" a native `call` with the disassembly window).

Guess what I found:
[image]

The .NET framework generated a stub that is calling `memcpy`, and it fails when it tries to copy into `edi`, which at that time had the value 0x16 (==22), which was the parameter sent in the C# code!

So, lets see what would happen if I were to send a valid pointer to the function:

```
unsafe
{
    long* ptr = &something;
    uint ptr_value = (uint)ptr;
    Console.WriteLine("Pointer address: {0:X}", (long)ptr);

    var statusBlock = someFn(ptr_value);
    Console.WriteLine("A: {0}", statusBlock.statusA);

    Console.WriteLine("B: {0:X}", statusBlock.statusB);
}
```

Output: (it works and doesn't crash when a valid pointer is given!)

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(StatusBlock)) = 8
Running .NET Version 2
Pointer address: 49F15C
A: 0
B: 0
```

So, I conclude this is an unsalvageable problem in .NET Framework 2.

### Why is it happening?

When a C function is defined to return a `struct` larger than 8 bytes, the function shall actually return a pointer to the `struct` in the local function's `stack` and the caller should use `memcpy` to copy it to it's own `stack` (this is a part of C's specifications and is implemented by the compiler - the programmer simply "returns" a struct and the compiler does the heavy lifting).

However, for 8 bytes (either `struct` or `long long`), most C compilers return it in `eax:edx`. Probably .NET's developers have missed that. The mistake is probably that someone wrote `size >= 8` instead `size > 8`...

Edit: What's worse, it writes the result on the pointer given!

```
before: 0x1111222244445555
after : 0x1234ABCD007BEF5C
```

It changes the pointer to be the return value! As you can see, the first `dword` after the call is is 0x1234ABCD (as in the native DLL) and the second `dword` is the pointer to the value, i.e the parameter `someVal` that was given!

It's even more funny, because if you pass a pointer to a `StatusBlock` struct - it will actually work for this specific case (because the first `dword` in the return value is used as a pointer)

## Solution

Return a `long` variable and make the struct yourself.

Comment: I suspected this was a bug, but thanks for proving it with the excellent analysis! As a work around I've been doing exactly what you suggested; marshal the return value as 64 bit `int` and provide a conversion constructor on `StatusBlock` to do the mapping.